# Codename one push all push failing after one fails

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, codenameone

When sending a push notification using the a list of device ID's using the Codename One server I've noticed that if the first in a batch of devices fails then none of the other ones are sent.
In this case the first one is for a user who has uninstalled the app.
I was under the impression the server would return a json object with a list for each device which ones have failed an succeeded.
I'm fairly sure this used to work, but seems to have been broken

Comment: Can you provide the specific error message?

Comment: Seems to be returning nothing at all when it fails in this way

Comment: It never returns nothing. At most it will return an empty array or map but it won't return nothing.

Comment: It does seem to return an empty array, but you were asking about the specfic error message: nothing.

Comment: I've reviewed the code and can't see any place where an exception or failure occurs in which we don't write a specific error message. Trying to narrow it down can you reproduce this with two device key's? The first will fail and the second won't be reached? If so what's the type of these two keys (android/iOS)?